# What is the best data structure for a collection of words?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, collections

I have a collection of about 170,000 words and I perform a number of operations on them.  The most common are: [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx), [EndsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith.aspx) and [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx).  I also do a lot of length checking.

I originally stored this information in a `List<string>` but then switched to a `HashSet<string>` because I thought it would be faster for this type of data.

Based on what I have described, is a HashSet the best type of collection for this data?

Comment: `StartsWith` and, by storing reversed strings or indexing inside out, `EndsWith` can benefit from a sorted structure, e.g. a binary tree.  `Contains` doesn't admit to performance enhancements quite so easily, though length may be a useful tidbit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is a very good data structure for storing strings and performing the text searching operations you need.  It is the data structure commonly used to index string values for use in search engines such as Lucene

Normally when mentioned, a trie is described as a prefix tree which allows for very efficient 'begins with' searching.  The [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) variation of the data structure is very efficient at 'ends with' searching.

Conceivably, the same trie implementation could be used for both prefix and suffix trees by simply reversing strings when populating the trie as well as when searching the trie.

Comment: +1 Do you know of some .NET C# sample code for trie? (for a list of about 170000 words)

Comment: @Blam I do not know of an implementation off hand.  A quick internet search should uncover several C# implementations.  For large lists it may be best to use one that allows for using the file system for storing the trie.

Comment: Did search. Will keep looking.  Just was hoping you had one you liked.  Trie is ironically a term that search engines like to get smart with.

Comment: @Blam the best and most readable implementation for a trie that I've found is in my answer. Leveraging the framework keeps it simpler and very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

The operations you've mentioned are all being done on *individual elements* of the collection, so they're totally ignorant of what type of collection your elements are actually coming from.

The important things to consider with collection types is in what way do you work with the entire collection: do you insert items a lot, or remove them frequently? Do you want to get at each element in order, or do you want to access a specific part of the collection more frequently. Can the collection have duplicate elements? Do you need to check membership? Does it matter in which order you process them?

These are the types of questions you need to answer to make an informed decision about different collection types.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are trying to find matches which `StartsWith`, `EndWith` or `Contains` some search term. If that's the case then you are correct in that `List` is not ideal. I don't believe `Hashset` is any better.

Check out the [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). I wouldn't build one, but if gives some context about the problem space. The algorithm involves grouping words by their initial substring - group words based on their first letter, then sub group by the second letter, and so on.

When I've done this in the past I've made use of both the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class and also implemented `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

The algorithm I've used is roughly

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Lookup<string, string>>();
for (int i = 1; i < maxWordLength; i++)
{
    // get all words with i or more letters
    dictionary.Add(i, words.ToLookup(w => w.Substring(i)));
}
```

and then finding a word like

```
var word = "TestWord";
var matches = dictionary[word.Length][word];
```

If you also need `EndsWith` and `Contains` you will presumably need a number of index structures for those too.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/).  However, if you're determined to implement your own algorithm (whatever that may be) then your best bet is to take advantage of C#'s powerful parallel looping constructs in Parallel.ForEach and PLINQ.

[Data Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608)

[Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx)

i.e.

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(100, 20000);

// Result sequence might be out of order.
var parallelQuery = from num in source.AsParallel()
                    where num % 10 == 0
                    select num;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is probably an array of strings as it has the lowest overhead, if the list is static.

And then use multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Ran a test and did not get the answer I expected. List and HashSet and AsParallel about the same (but only 2 core machine). .NET 4.0 and a list of 600,000 words.

I echo the first comment.  When in doubt test.  l is List and h is HashSet.

```
Debug.WriteLine("lWords.Count hWords.Count " + lWords.Count.ToString() + " " + hWords.Count.ToString());
Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch();
SW.Restart();
Debug.WriteLine("H count " + hWords.Where(value => value.StartsWith("s")).Count().ToString());
SW.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("H time " + SW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
SW.Restart();
SW.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Start Stop " + SW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
SW.Restart();
Debug.WriteLine("L count " + lWords.Where(value => value.StartsWith("s")).Count().ToString());
SW.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("L time " + SW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
SW.Restart();
Debug.WriteLine("H count " + hWords.Where(value => value.StartsWith("s")).Count().ToString());
SW.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("H time " + SW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
SW.Restart();
Debug.WriteLine("L count " + lWords.AsParallel().Where(value => value.StartsWith("s")).Count().ToString());
SW.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("L time parallel " + SW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
SW.Restart();
Debug.WriteLine("H count " + hWords.AsParallel().Where(value => value.StartsWith("s")).Count().ToString());
SW.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("H time parallel " + SW.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine("");

output:
lWords.Count hWords.Count 667309 667309
H count 45851
H time 283
Start Stop 0
L count 45851
L time 285
H count 45851
H time 364
L count 45851
L time parallel 307
H count 45851
H time parallel 344
```